# Format tab in Ektron's Aloha editor: not loading plugins/ektron/format/format-plugin.js and need to add a button

Tags: ektron, aloha-editor

Using Ektron 9.00 SP3

I'm trying to figure out why Ektron's plugin/ektron/format plugin is not being loaded.  The goal is to add a span button missing under the tag buttons under the Format tab in the Aloha editor and add a div button as well.  The base format plugin (as can be seen on Ektron's developer.ektron.com site when editing or adding a forum post) has a span button, but my site's instance does not. I tried to update the format-plugin.js under ektron/format/lib/ to add a div button right before the span button by updating the config setting, adding a div case right before the span case, and adding a div tooltip in the corresponding i18n.js file, but the div button is not showing up.

This led me to believe that the format-plugin.js is not being loaded.  Using Firebug and setting the js aggregation to false, I confirmed that it is not being loaded.  I also confirmed that ektron/format is in the ektron.cms.framework.ui.config in all of the templates and that ektron/format is appearing in the list of plugins to load.  So it should be loaded, but it's not.  I am not receiving any errors on the Firebug Console relating to jQuery or Aloha, either.

Is there any reason why the format-plugin.js would not be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

That file may not be used any more. The file that builds the span buttons is

/WorkArea/FrameworkUI/js/ektron/Controls/EktronUI/Editor/Aloha/plugins/ektron/general/lib/general-plugin.js

Comment: I do not think the general-plugin.js on my instance seems to be affecting the span buttons.  I reviewed the code and I could not find anything that related to that.  What version of Ektron are you referring to/using?

Comment: I was looking at 9.1 SP1. I guess it must have changed.